# will index be used when UPPER() the variable first?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I ***may*** have encountered a full table scan in Oracle database. I can't excute the `explain` command in the database, simply put, I don't have the permission.
And I'm trying to figure out the following question.

If I have an index on `NAME` in `table`

With this query:

```
select OID 
from table 
where NAME=UPPER(v1) 
  and TYPE=v2 
  and PID=v3 
  and OID<>v4 
  and PID =v5`
```

(v1 is a variable)

Will the oracle use index on `name` to select `OID`?

I have read some material, and it says with a function in where condition the `NAME` index won't be used. But the upper() is a special function, so I'm not quiet sure about the material I saw before.

And here is the second question after the answer of @mathguy:

If I create an index using `create index INDEX_NAME on table(upper(NAME));`

will the query:

```
select OID,PID 
from table 
where PID=v1 
  and NAME=UPPER(v2)
```

use the index INDEX_NAME?

**OR the index will be used in the above question, and the query is just not efficient so they take much time to execute?**

Comment: 1. How do you know it's full scanning if you can't see the query plan? 2. Full scans are not always bad! (e.g. if your table is not large)

Comment: If it makes sense, then yes Oracle will use an index on `name`

Comment: What you said about permission makes no sense. Are you a developer? If you are not, why do you care about indexes and FTS? So I will assume you are a developer. If so, what sort of morons (sorry for the harsh language) would hire you to be a developer, but then prevent you from doing your job properly by not allowing you to run explain plans? Go to your manager and see if they will change that.

Comment: @LordPeter someone point out it is a full table scan, and the table is very large, the select takes maybe 7-9s to finish.

Comment: @mathguy, it is a analogy. I just can't access the target database, and oracle is not a free database, and I asume I can't install it in the computer to test it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your great editing.

Comment: You assume wrong. You can install the free Express Edition (XE) of Oracle and use it for anything you want. You can also install and use non-free editions (I use the Enterprise Edition, EE) **for free** as long as it is **for evaluation or learning purposes only**. I don't work in the field, and I use the EE (with all the Oracle features, and version 12.1 which is not available in XE), for free, since I am only learning on it, not using it for anything else. For all other uses you can always use XE for free.

Comment: @Thank you for the XE editon, I will try it to test all my doubts. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have lots of comments already, but here's a last one. Make sure that the data in the NAME column of the table is actually in upper case otherwise if NAME ='LordPeter' then it won't match Upper('LordPeter') which is 'LORDPETER'. Lots more info on your main question if you search for "SARGABLE".

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on `name`, then the optimizer MAY use the index in the example you gave. It may choose not to use it (for example if it estimates that a relatively large fraction of rows will be returned anyway); but if say only 0.1% of rows would be returned, by all means the index will be used. (If that still doesn't happen, make sure statistics are up-to-date.)

What will prevent the use of an index is if you wrapped `name` within `upper()`. What happens on the right-hand side - whether you have `v1` or `upper(v1)` or even a much more complicated expression - is irrelevant **as long as** `name` **doesn't also appear in that complicated expression** on the right-hand side.

Comment: According the [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1161), if I create index on UPPER(NAME), and select something from table where name = UPPER(NAME), the UPPER(NAME) index will be used.

Comment: The customer says it triggerd a full table scan using its homegrow tool.

Comment: I'm updating the question with the full sql statemet trigged full table scan.

Comment: @EvanL00: but you do not have an `upper(name)` in the query of your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yeah, so what I try to figure out is without the UPPER()  will index be hit.. PS: thank you for your great editing.

Comment: @mathguy, that is to say if I use UPPER(NAME) to create index, and select SOMETHING where NAME= v1 will not trigger a full table scan. Is my understand correctly?

Comment: @EvanL00 - to try to use your suggested function-based index you'd have to do `where UPPER(NAME)= v1` or `... = UPPER(v1)`. And it would still only use it the optimiser decided it was the best option. You're filtering on five fields, the optimiser is apparently deciding that a full scan is the best way to fulfil those, and the `UPPER(v1)` in your existing query won't affect the plan chosen.

Comment: @AlexPoole the first question is different from the function-based index.  The index is created on `NAME`, and in the where conditon it perform a `upper()` function on `v1`. I have read some material, and it says with a function in where condition the index won't be used. BUt the `upper()` is special function, so I want an certaincy.

Comment: And you've been told twice that using `UPPER(v1)` on the variable, rather than the column, makes no difference. The FBI stuff is confusing matters, but would only be (potentially) helpful if you *were* having to apply the function to the column value as well. Re-read that material again, unless it's badly written it should say a function *on the indexed column value* in the where condition will stop an index being used, not any function call anywhere.

Comment: @ Thank you, I will re-read the material and find a better one(since the material is not clear).

Comment: @AlexPoole THANK YOU for your help, your comment make me get more understanding!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help...

In Oracle, you can create an index on a function (a function index), so if you created your index on the function UPPER(NAME) instead of just NAME, Oracle may be more likely to use the index (although it still might choose not to depending on other factors.)

Here's a [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes) that describes function indexes

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would an FBI be useful for the OP's scenario, where only the variable is converted, not the column value?

Comment: @AlexPoole I was thinking since oracle is case sensitive, to compare the UPPER(Variable) to the column, then the column should be indexed as Upper.

Comment: That may be a legitimate change to the query, and then an FBI might be helpful; but not sure it's in scope here - the OP doesn't currently appear to need to do that, and we don't know if all  values in the table are uppercase already. An FBI won't help the original query.